# Custom Attribute for the attribute that can browse through multiple pages (JQuery & HTML)

Tags: jquery, slider

I created a menu which browses through a list of slide on a specific page.

The HTML Code for it is as follows:-

```
 <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="2"><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">When to do it</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="3" ><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Key faces</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="5" ><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Functionalities</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Notice the "custom attribute" for the  tag, which tells me which slide to browse to.

This JS code allows me to do that:-

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(){
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        window.slider.go(false, slideToJump+1);
    });
});
```

As you can see that it gets the number of the slide on the page and just jumps on it.

The slides are all on the same page, so basically this code move slides on the same page and takes me whichever slide I wanna go. My problem is now that I've been trying to move slides on another page now.

So if I click a link to move to a different page with a specific slide number, how would I able to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: As a sidenote, it's considered a good practice to use delegated events when binding same element to a large collections, instead of binding event to each element. Like this 
    `$('.dropdown').on('click', 'a[data-jumpslide]', function(){
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        window.slider.go(false, slideToJump+1);
    });`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I'll definitely change this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass that slide value to the next page as a hash tag.

The pages should include a script that checks that hastag value:

```
window.location.hash;
```

Then simply pass that hash value to the slide selector function.

To get the href and the hashtag, you just modify what you have currently:

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        slideToJump++;
        window.location(href+'#'+slideToJump);
    });
});
```

Then your target href should have something like this to capture the hashtag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    window.slider.go(false, hash);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks ... may be I could do it by adding another attribute with <a> tag. something like:- <a href="#" data-jumpslide="2" goto-page="new-page-name#2"> ... this attribute would have the name of the page, we wanna go to. I can add the slide number with the name (the way I added 2 with it as a slide number). Is this what you meant?

Comment: Exactly, I would use the href attribute and prevent the default event by doing a `e.preventDefault`.  Capture the href and if it exists, fire of a `window.location(href+hashtag);`

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful assistance 4m1r! But while implementing it, I am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'location' of object [object global] is not a function"... precisely on window.location where it should be redirecting. Any idea about that? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, to make it work I changed the window.location(href+...) line to var url = href+'#'+slideToJump;
                window.location = url;